# Store multiple values to local storage from a single input box and submit button and return them to feed other buttons

Tags: javascript, html

New to coding, 7 weeks into a bootcamp class. I am trying to save multiple city names from an input search window with a submit button to local storage and return those names to populate 8 button boxes that I can click on to execute another search with these saved names. Right now I am only able to save one value and it returns that same value to all 8 buttons. Below my JS and HTML code.

```
var wantCity = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
wantCity.addEventListener('click', mySave,);

function mySave () {
  var myContent = document.getElementById('inputCity').value;
  localStorage.setItem('myContent', myContent);

  event.preventDefault(mySave);
}

var myContent = localStorage.getItem('myContent');
document.getElementById('city1').value = myContent;

var myContent2 = localStorage.getItem('myContent');
document.getElementById('city2').value = myContent2;

var myContent = localStorage.getItem('myContent');
document.getElementById('city3').value = myContent;

var myContent = localStorage.getItem('myContent');
document.getElementById('city4').value = myContent;

var myContent = localStorage.getItem('myContent');
document.getElementById('city5').value = myContent;

var myContent = localStorage.getItem('myContent');
document.getElementById('city6').value = myContent;

var myContent = localStorage.getItem('myContent');
document.getElementById('city7').value = myContent;

var myContent = localStorage.getItem('myContent');
document.getElementById('city8').value = myContent;
```

Here's the HTML portion:

```html
<div class="container" id="weatherInfo">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" class="cityRequest" id="infoBox">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <label id="inputValue">Enter City Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="inputCity"
               class="nameOfCity">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2" type="button" id="submitBtn">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group" class="previousCities">
        <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities"
               id="city1">
        <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities"
               id="city2">
        <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities"
               id="city3">
        <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities"
               id="city4">
        <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities"
               id="city5">
        <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities"
               id="city6">
        <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities"
               id="city7">
        <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities"
               id="city8">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store and retrieve multiple values in localStorage, you need to save an array or object.

And since localStorage only stores strings, you need to convert that array/object to a string before storage.

```js
let cities = [];
let iCity = 0;

...
// store one city to cities array
cities[iCity++] = document.getElementById('inputCity').value;
localStorage('myContent', JSON.stringify(cities));

...
// update the city inputs
cities = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myContent'));
for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById(`city${i+1}`).value = cities[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a shot.